# How to find recognize certain shape in image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm

So I want to find a certain shape in a videostream (for example a certain starshape in a drawing when a camera is pointed to it). I have extracted HOG desciptorvalues of a single image of the shape I want to search (I took the canny of the image). How do I use these descriptorvalues with SVM to find the shape on an other image or videostream and draw a boundary box around it? Maybe an easier method than HoG?

Example with pictures:
[Shape I want to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiZLZ.png),
[Example of wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ff6.jpg)

```
vector<float> descVal;
vector<Point> loc;
hog.compute( image_canny, descVal, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), loc);
```

Comment: you will need to train an svm with enough data samples (https://sarthakahuja.org/public/docs/report_ped_detection.pdf there are some tutorials in the internet too, afair). But as a hint: I think using the canny result as hog input might not be a good approach, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: But the shape always stays the same, is it necessary  for multiple datasamples?

Comment: svm is a machine learning technique. If the shape really stays the same (especially concerning rotation) you should be able to use much more simple approaches like chamfer matching, which will probably be faster, too.

Comment: if you just want to use hog, you can compare the descriptors directly with the reference in a euclidean distance metric or in a histogram comparison metric. No need to use svm if you don't want to "learn" something. If you still want to use svm with a single reference image, use some data augmentation and you will still need a lot of "negative" samples for training, where your object is not present, unless you ist a "one-class-svm training".

Comment: Hello, I have added some pictures to make it more clear what I want to achieve. Is this possible with euclidean distance?

Comment: Local descriptors will perform poorly on this case because the target image contains many similar features and there are many opportunities for confusion. IMO, a structural description of the shape (as a sequence of line segments and circular arcs) would be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, but this is just an example shape, I want to use more complex shapes which aren't possible to describe with line segments and circular arcs.

Comment: I think I am going to use OCR because shapes seem difficult